# What is Saitama reading?

Tags: one-punch-man

In the *One Punch Man* manga, Saitama is often shown reading recently published and popular manga. In the anime, you can often see his bookshelf filled with manga.

[image: Bookshelf in Saitama's room containing many manga]

I suspect that the designs come from real manga series, but I am not well versed with the appearance of manga spines, nor can I read the blurry text on the spines.

Is there any idea where series/serials are from?

Comment: Might be a parody of existing manga, the clearest spine on the bottom shelf reads 少年ヨンデー (*Shonen Yonde*) which is a parody of 少年サンデー (*Shonen Sunday* magazine)

Comment: Well, Yusuke Murata did draw https://twitter.com/HxHSource/status/954055097524273152 to celebrate Yoshihiro Togashi's 50th birthday. Apart from the HXH reference, the first stack of books on the first shelf at least to me seems like a reference to Dragon Ball.

Comment: Also related from [Yahoo! Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20161021075517AApKPvc) and [Yahoo! Chiebukuro (Japanese)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12152625967): the first series on the top shelf looks like making an image of a dragon (could be *Dragon Ball* as per Gary's comment), the next series seems from ero love-comedy, the second shelf has ある馬鹿の人生 series by 本々はじめ (both fictitious title and author). The rest is too blurry to be recognized.